# How I will change my date and time to my country time in my PHP table query

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have table query from MY SQl database. My table look like this [my table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnLG4.png) I just want to change my table date and time to my country date and time. Here is my database image [my database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otN8e.png). my table date and time pull out from "created" rows.in my database. Here is my table code.`

```html
<div class="row">
  <div id="middlecolumn" align="center">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>

          <th id="tabletext">
            <?php echo $lang['send']; ?>
          </th>
          <th id="tabletext">
            <?php echo $lang['receive']; ?>
          </th>
          <th id="tabletext">
            <?php echo $lang['amount']; ?>
          </th>
          <th id="tabletext">
            <?php echo $lang['exchange_id']; ?>
          </th>
          <th id="tabletext">
            <?php echo $lang['status']; ?>
          </th>
          <th id="tabletext">
            <?php echo $lang['date_time']; ?>
          </th>

        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <?php
                                            $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM bit_exchanges ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5000"); 
                                            if($query->num_rows>0) {
                                                while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
                                                    ?>
          <tr>
            <td id="tabletext"><img src="<?php echo gatewayicon(gatewayinfo($row['gateway_send']," name ")); ?>" width="20px" height="20">
              <?php echo gatewayinfo($row['gateway_send'],"name"); ?>
            </td>
            <td id="tabletext"><img src="<?php echo gatewayicon(gatewayinfo($row['gateway_receive']," name ")); ?>" width="20px" height="20">
              <?php echo gatewayinfo($row['gateway_receive'],"name"); ?>
            </td>
            <td id="tabletext">
              <?php echo $row['amount_send']; ?>
              <?php echo gatewayinfo($row['gateway_send'],"currency"); ?>
            </td>
            <td id="tabletext">
              <?php echo cropexchangeid($row['exchange_id'],8); ?>
            </td>
            <td id="tabletext">
              <?php 
                                        if($row['status'] == "1") {
                                            echo '<span class="label label-warning"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> '.$lang[status_1].'</span>';
                                        } elseif($row['status'] == "2") {
                                            echo '<span class="label label-warning"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> '.$lang[status_2].'</span>';
                                        } elseif($row['status'] == "3") {
                                            echo '<span class="label label-info"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> '.$lang[status_3].'</span>';
                                        } elseif($row['status'] == "4") {
                                            echo '<span class="label label-success"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> '.$lang[status_4].'</span>';
                                        } elseif($row['status'] == "5") {
                                            echo '<span class="label label-danger"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> '.$lang[status_5].'</span>';
                                        } elseif($row['status'] == "6") {
                                            echo '<span class="label label-danger"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> '.$lang[status_6].'</span>';
                                        } elseif($row['status'] == "7") {
                                            echo '<span class="label label-danger"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> '.$lang[status_7].'</span>';
                                        } else {
                                            echo '<span class="label label-default">'.$lang[status_unknown].'</span>';
                                        }
                                        ?>
            </td>
            <td id="tabletext">
              <?php echo date("d/m/Y H:i:s",$row['created']) ?>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <?php
                                                }
                                            } else {
                                                echo '<tr><td colspan="5">'.$lang[still_no_exchanges].'</td></tr>';
                                            }
                                            ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```